# VueRouter does not receive meta property in router-link tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to pass `meta` fields via `<router-link>` tag. Like this:

```
<router-link :to="{path: '/inlineMeta', meta: {title: 'Inline meta'}}">
    Inline meta
</router-link>
```

I want to achieve this because I can dynamically pass metas from a backend framework directly on the tag itself. Declaring `routes` option in a JS file simply does not have that power.

Theoretically, any object passed via *to* prop should be pushed to `router` stack right? But in this case it doesn't seem like so.

If I declare `meta` in `routes` option, it definitely works. There is no doubt about that.

I wonder if it's possible to do so, and how would I do that?

---

A small fiddle to illustrate the problem. Click on URLs and notice the console. I can't get StackOverflow snippet to work properly.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HuyPham55/psky0j29/14/)

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const cComponent = {
  data() {
    return {
      fetchedData: null
    }
  },
  template: `<div>The meta is: {{$route.meta.title}}</div>`,
}
const routes = [{
    path: "/inlineMeta",
    component: cComponent,
  },
  {
    path: "/routeMeta",
    meta: {
      title: 'Meta declared in routes'
    },
    component: cComponent,
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes,
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log("The meta title is : " + to.meta.title);
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="   https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.5.1/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <router-link :to="{path: '/inlineMeta', meta: {title: 'Inline meta'}}">Inline meta</router-link>
  <router-link :to="{path: '/routeMeta'}">Meta declared in routes</router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: Having to declare `meta` in the route makes no sense, it defeats the purpose of allowing уоu to pass arbitrary data. There doesn't seem to be a way to pass data other than in `query`, but that makes it appear in the URL. And you can't pass it in `params` since v4.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the parameters between two components,  use `props`.
`v-bind:to` in `<route-link>` is just used for route match, so you can't use it to set the value of meta.
If you want to set the meta without declaring it in route, i think using "this.$route.meta.title="Inline meta" " in js.
like using the click event:

```
<li @click="setMeta">
  <router-link :to="{path: '/inlineMeta'}">
    Inline meta
  </router-link>
</li>
```

and in js:

```
method:{
    setMeta(){
      this.$route.meta.title="Inline meta";
    }
}
```

you can also use `mounted()` in the new component you just routed to like :

```
mounted(){
  this.$route.meta.title="Inline meta"
}
```

and meta will be modified after reloading
This may work though it may looks not that elegant.

Comment: Not sure if you've read the question. I'm not trying to pass parameters between two component...

Comment: now i get that, are you trying to pass the information of meta by <router-link :to="{path: '/inlineMeta', meta: {title: 'Inline meta'}}"> without declaring meta in route?  v-bind:to is just used for route match, so you can't use it to set the value. If you want to set the meta without declaring it in route, i think usintg"this.$route.meta.title="Inline meta" " in js may work though it may looks not that elegant

Comment: Declaring in JS file is not an option for me. Could we somehow use `this.$route.meta.title="Inline meta"` in somewhere like `<router-link>`?

Comment: At second thought, I don't think you are wrong. However it raise another problem: The method will not trigger itself on page reload, but only on click event. Is there any idea to solve that as well?

Comment: I've tried several ways, but it seems that the only way to set the value in html tag is `v-model` . and for second thought, @click is just an example, `watch` is a better way, and use `mounted` to trigger when page reload

Comment: Would you mind illustrate an overall idea on that by editting the answer? Are you trying to create a `router-link` component that replicates `<router-link>` tag, then implement `mounted` within it?